# Formatting the zipped arrays - TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python, arrays, zip

I want to zip below data however, I get TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration. 
I have indicated the expected result.
Is there anybody who could help me? Thanks.

```
nn_inputs = []
for speed, occupancy, capacity in zip(speed, occupancy,capacity):
    nn_input = zip(int(speed),int(occupancy), float(capacity))
    nn_inputs.append(nn_input)

print nn_inputs


Data input: 

speed = [-24 , -15 , -9 ] 
occupancy = [15, 3, 4] 
capacity = [1.47056441941, 2.12024661067, 2.47288942169 ]



Expected result:

[-24, 15 , 1.47056441941]
[-15, 3  , 2.12024661067]
[-9 , 4  , 2.47288942169]
```

Comment: Your "numbers" are not numbers, they're strings.

Comment: I have converted them into float. However, I get this error now: TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration  @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Now, that is better, right; it shows where the problem is.

Comment: int(speed) converts a list to an int, not a list of int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `zip` once:

```
>>> speed = [-24 , -15 , -9 ]
>>> occupancy = [15, 3, 4]
>>> capacity = [1.47056441941, 2.12024661067, 2.47288942169 ]
>>> nn_inputs = zip(speed, occupancy, capacity)
>>> nn_inputs
[(-24, 15, 1.47056441941), (-15, 3, 2.12024661067), (-9, 4, 2.47288942169)]
```

Result is list of tuples; if you want list of lists, you can do

```
>>> nn_inputs = map(list, zip(speed, occupancy, capacity))
>>> nn_inputs
[[-24, 15, 1.47056441941], [-15, 3, 2.12024661067], [-9, 4, 2.47288942169]]
```

Comment: Thank you! @AnttiHaapala